# SQL INSERT ISSUE WITH CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that I am working on. The goal is to insert the [AppID] and randomly selected [ufid] that meet the criteria in the where clause without inserting duplicates. I have researched the TABLESAMPLE and Random() but was unable to figure this out.

For example: #mult_nuf table has 4 records with the  AppID = 123456 and Major = 'GEBOX'. The #temp_rUF will have a record in the table with the ufid = 'UF7' and sh_plan = 'GEBOX'.I need to insert the [App_ID] and the [ufid] of another [sh_plan] into a temp table WHERE the [Major] and [sh_plan] are NOT be the same. So far a record for every [ufid] is being inserted with the same [Appid]. I have 45 [ufid} in the table so the temp table has 45 records for the same [AppID]. Should only be 4 records for the [AppID] with 4 random [ufid]..

## mult_nuf table

```
AppID              Major
004540036          GEBOX
004540036          GEBOX
004540036          GEBOX
004540036          GEBOX
```

The #temp_ruf table

```
ufID                  sh_Plan
U1                    GECCE
U2                    REDSG
U5                    GFRTY
U7                    GEBOX
U8                    JKIUTY
```

Sample Output should look like

```
App_ID              ufID
004540036              U1
004540036              U2
004540036              U5
004540036              U8
```

Query I am working with

```
WITH Match_NomineesWithReviewers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [AppID], 
        RTRIM(Major) AS Major
    FROM  
        #mult_nuf
)
SELECT 
    m.[AppID], 
    r.ufid
INTO 
    #TempNTable
FROM 
    Match_NWithR m
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT ir.ufid
     FROM #temp_rUF ir
     WHERE m.Major <> ir.sh_plan) r
```

Comment: This question really needs sample data and sample output based on that data.

Comment: I added sample data and output. thxs

Comment: It's confusing because what you describe doesn't match the data you provided. For instance sh_plan and ufid are not named the same in your examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this on a set of AppID's, I'd use ROW_NUMBER and ORDER BY newid() for random, then limit to the first 4 results, something like this:

```
WITH Match_NomineesWithReviewers AS
(
    SELECT 
        [AppID], 
        RTRIM(Major) AS Major
    FROM  
        #mult_nuf
    GROUP BY
        [AppID], 
        RTRIM(Major)
)
, rownum_matches AS (
SELECT 
    m.[AppID], 
    r.ufid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.[AppID] ORDER BY newid()) AS rownum
FROM 
    Match_NomineesWithReviewers m
JOIN
    #temp_rUF t ON t.sh_Plan != m.Major
 )
 SELECT [AppID], ufid FROM rownum_matches WHERE rownum <= 4
```

If you need it to match the original number of records, maybe something like this:

```
WITH Match_NomineesWithReviewers AS
(
    SELECT 
        [AppID], 
        RTRIM(Major) AS Major,
        COUNT(1) AS rowcnt
    FROM  
        #mult_nuf
    GROUP BY
        [AppID], 
        RTRIM(Major)
)
, rownum_matches AS (
SELECT 
    m.[AppID], 
    r.ufid,
    m.rowcnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.[AppID] ORDER BY newid()) AS rownum
FROM 
    Match_NomineesWithReviewers m
JOIN
    #temp_rUF t ON t.sh_Plan != m.Major
 )
SELECT [AppID], ufid FROM rownum_matches rm WHERE rownum <= rowcnt
```

Comment: This solution works great for my original post. However I didn't realize that the number of times that [ r.ufid] can be inserted into the temp table is based on a variable called @RevsRev (which is set to 42). Any ideas of the best way to add that functionality? Not sure if I need to create a new question since my original question posted has been answered?

Comment: Do you just need to limit the results to 42 or does it need to be done earlier on?  Something like WHERE rownum <= rowcnt AND rownum <= @RevsRev would work in the former case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. It should work if the appid's are all the same.

```
INSERT INTO ATempTable
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mult_nuf) Appid,
  ufID
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM mult_nuf
    CROSS JOIN temp_ruf
    WHERE major <> sh_plan) BaseQuery
ORDER BY NEWID()
```